# Fibonacci Sequence in tuple Python

Tags: python

To be writing a make_fibonacci that accepts a parameter n which generates and returns a tuple containing the first n+1 terms of the fibonacci sequence, where n>= 0. From the other questions here,

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(d):
        a, b = b, a+b
```

but since I need the range of the fibonacci in a tuple, like

```
make_fibonacci(10)  
>>> (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the error again , please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append it to a list:

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    fib = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a+b
        fib.append(a)
    return tuple(fib)


make_fibonacci(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

here's a naive solution, construct as a list and return a tuple

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    a = [0, 1]
    [a.append(a[-1]+a[-2]) for i in xrange(n)]
    return tuple(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def fib(n):
    tup=[]
    a,b = 0,1
    while b<n:
        tup=tup+[b,]
        a,b = b,a+b
    print tup
```

You need to append to tuple and then print it if you like

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a list:

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    result = [0]
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n-1):
        a, b = b, a+b
        result.append(b)
    return tuple(result)


>>> print make_fibonacci(10)
(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one *purely* **works on tuples** and is free from lists.

***Conceptual Knowledge*** : *Two Tuples Can Be Added*

```
def get_fibonacci(n):  # n = no. of terms to be taken in tuple fibonacci_sequence
    a, b = 0, 1
    fibonacci_sequence = (a, b)
    for i in range(n-2):
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibonacci_sequence += (b,)  # Comma is needed at the end to accept a tuple with a single value
    print fibonacci_sequence
get_fibonacci(10)
```

***Note***: This has been tested on Python Console v2.7.12, and it might not work on Python 3.x and later versions. If you find it working, well and fine, please correct this statement.
 *Positive Modifications are always Welcome!*

Answer (score 0):

```
fib = (0,1,1)
print(fib)
for i in range(10):
    fib = fib + (fib[i+1] + fib[i+2],)
print(fib)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.